# Using Autofac's ReplaceInstance with interface types

Tags: c#, autofac

According to the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/LifetimeEvents), I can use the activating event to "Switch the instance for another or wrap it in a proxy," but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Here's what I've tried:

```
[TestFixture]
public class ReplaceInstanceTest
{
    public interface ISample { }
    public class Sample : ISample { }
    public class ProxiedSample : ISample {
        private readonly ISample _sample;
        public ProxiedSample(ISample sample) {
            _sample = sample;
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void ReplaceInstance_can_proxy_for_interface_type()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<Sample>()
               .As<ISample>()
               .OnActivating(x =>
                  x.ReplaceInstance(new ProxiedSample(x.Instance)))
               .SingleInstance();
        var container = builder.Build();

        var sample = container.Resolve<ISample>();
        Assert.That(sample, Is.InstanceOf<ProxiedSample>());
    }

}
```

The above results in a class cast exception because autofac is trying to cast `ProxiedSample` to a `Sample` instance, which it is not.

Is it possible to use `ReplaceInstance` on the [ActivatingEvent](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/LifetimeEvents) to proxy an object in autofac (2.6 or 3.0)?

I know it's possible to use [RegisterDecorator](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AdaptersAndDecorators), but my actual implementation both configures and conditionally proxies, so I'd prefer to use the activating event, if it's possible.

Comment: just a fast comment (not near it atm to check) - but shouldn't you just use `ISample` then instead of `Sample`. You can't put Proxied into Sample. Though not sure about your model internals.

Comment: I don't understand your point. `Resolve` should return an instance of `Sample` which is passed to the `OnActivating` handler and passed as an argument to `ProxiedSample`?

Comment: What I had in mind and what I usually prefer (a more manual creation construct with lambda) - is something like `builder.Register<ISample>(c => new ProxiedSample(new Sample())).SingleInstance();` (I'm paraphrasing for your case, I don't know if that fits). Or `builder.Register<ProxiedSample>(c => new ProxiedSample(new Sample())).As<ISample>().SingleInstance();`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Travis responded on the autofac list [detailing some of the challenges surrounding this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/autofac/BPdp3RpGbBw). Between his comments and NSGaga's suggestions I came up with the following workaround:

```
[Test]
public void ReplaceInstance_can_proxy_for_interface_type_when_using_multi_stage_registration()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<Sample>().AsSelf();
    builder.Register(c => (ISample)c.Resolve<Sample>())
           .OnActivating(x => x.ReplaceInstance(new ProxiedSample(x.Instance)))
           .SingleInstance();
    var container = builder.Build();

    var sample = container.Resolve<ISample>();
    Assert.That(sample, Is.InstanceOf<ProxiedSample>());
}
```

It's possible to make the registration more compact:

```
builder.Register<ISample>(c => new Sample()).OnActivating(/*...*/);
```

The downfall of this approach is that if the `Sample` constructor changes the registration will have to change as well, which I avoided with the additional registration of the concrete type.